# Attempt at Proving map between Coproduct and Product is Epic in Abelian Category

Tags: proof-verification, abelian-categories, morphism

I have come up with this diagram where the map $f : A \times B \rightarrow A$ is surjective. We define $j = coker(\pi_a, \pi_b)$. I know that $j \circ (\pi_a, \pi_b) = 0$ so that the composition of the maps on the top row is $0$ map from $A \rightarrow Z$. Commutativity gives us that traveling down through the bottom row also gives us 0 map. Since $\phi$ is the only non-identity map, $\phi$ is 0 map. We see that $j = f \circ \phi$ so that $j = 0$. Therefore, $(\pi_a, \pi_b)$ is epic.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    A @>i_a>> A \sqcup B @>(\pi_a, \pi_b)>> A \times B @>j>> Z\\
    @|  @. @VfVV @|\\ A @= A @= A @>\phi>> Z
\end{CD}

I am not sure that $f$ exists since Aluffi never seems to mention it in his proof in Chapter 9.1. Can we assume $f$ is the projection map $\pi_a$?

Comment: I don't understand what you've taken $f$ to be. You say that it's surjective and observe that $j = \phi \circ f$ (you currently have a typo in the composition, by the way), but then express doubt about the identity and existence of $f?$ How did you get this diagram?

Comment: I threw together some random diagram that fits perfectly except for one small assumption that we can project from products onto individual part (which the book never discusses). I wanted to know if the idea is still correct but there's a way to get around the fact that we don't know if such an f exists.

Comment: Of course there is a projection $A \times B \to A,$ but not every diagram you can draw automatically commutes. If you want to define $\phi$ by commutativity of the small square, you must explain why $j$ factors through $A.$ Otherwise, you have simply defined $\phi$ to be $0$ (the only map $A \to Z$ that we're already aware of is the upper composition, which is $0$), so the claim $j = \phi \circ f$ is no more obvious than what you set out to prove.